# How to specify the no. of operations 'n', and thread count inside the yaml file to perform cassandra-stress

Tags: cassandra, yaml, cassandra-stress

This is code in the file example.yaml, It is used to perform cassandra-stress testing on the table staff_activites.
Actually I want to run 100000 insert operations while stressing, I am able to do it by using the command

`./cassandra-stress user profile="../example.yaml" "ops(insert=1)" n=100000`

But I want build a workload comprising of multiple tables with diff no. of insert operations , I tried to specify it inside the yaml file, It is showing the error. Command used to run is

`./cassandra-stress user profile="../example.yaml" "ops(insert=1)"`

The code inside the example.yaml file is below

```
specname: example 
keyspace: example


keyspace_definition: |
  CREATE KEYSPACE example WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};

table: staff_activities


table_definition: |
  CREATE TABLE staff_activities (
        name text,
        when timeuuid,
        what text,
        PRIMARY KEY(name, when)
  )

columnspec:
  - name: name
    size: uniform(5..10) # The names of the staff members are between 5-10 characters
    population: uniform(1..10) # 10 possible staff members to pick from
  - name: when
    cluster: uniform(20..500) # Staff members do between 20 and 500 events
  - name: what
    size: normal(10..100,50)

insert:
  partitions: fixed(1)
  select: fixed(1)/500
  batchtype: UNLOGGED  
  n: 1000              # n=1000 specifies 1000 operations          

queries:
   events:
      cql: select *  from staff_activities where name = ?
      fields: samerow
   latest_event:
      cql: select * from staff_activities where name = ?  LIMIT 1
      fields: samerow
```

Error faced is

```
Connected to cluster: Test Cluster, max pending requests per connection 128, max connections per host 8
Datacenter: dc1; Host: localhost/127.0.0.1; Rack: rack1
Created schema. Sleeping 1s for propagation.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognised insert option(s): {n=10}
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressProfile.getInsert(StressProfile.java:652)
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressProfile.printSettings(StressProfile.java:158)
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.lambda$printSettings$1(StressSettings.java:311)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.StressSettings.printSettings(StressSettings.java:311)
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.run(Stress.java:100)
        at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.main(Stress.java:67)
```